# Is there a simple way to sort a HashMap by values AND keys (Kotlin)?

Tags: sorting, kotlin, hashmap

I know hashmaps are not sorted by default. I also know you can easily sort a HashMap's keys by using map.toSortedMap(), and their values with map.toList().sortedBy { (_, value) -> value }.

But what if you wanted to sort both? I want to sort a hashmap first by values, and then, if the values are similar, by keys. I have mainly seen examples of this being done in Java, but the code can be quite extensive. Is there a simple, intuitive way of doing what I want?

Edit: To be a little bit more precise: I want to sort the hashmap objects by their values, BUT if some values are similar, I want to sort ONLY those objects by their keys as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of is to change the map into a list of pairs, sort it, and then make it a map again. Now take this with a grain of salt, as I honestly do not think that this might be the best way.

It will looks something like this:

```
val m = hashMapOf<String, String>()
m.map { it.key to it.value }.sortedBy { it.first + it.second }.toMap()
```

The sorting logic is `it.first + it.second` where `it.first` represents the `key` from the map, and `it.second` the value. You can change that logic to sort it however you like.

Also, the `.toMap()` won't give you `HashMap` back, but a `Map`, you can get it back by doing something like `HashMap(map)`, but then again, this whole process doesn't seem quite efficient to me.

Comment: That just sorts them by their keys. I am not sure how I am supposed to change the logic. What I want in the sortedBy clause is basically `.sortedBy{ if (it1.value == it2.value) keys }`

Comment: no, it does not sort them by the keys. I am quite confident that it sorts by the natural sorting order of `key + value`. And also, you know that there is no such thing as to identical keys in a map right?

Comment: My friend, I am not sure why you would insinuate that I don't. If the _values_ are similar, I want to sort by keys (which cannot, as you pointed out, be similar). This ensures the map will be sorted the way I need :-)

Comment: Alex, forgive my stupidness, and if I came off as passive agressive I apologise for this too. Your solution is perfect, and solved my problem!

Comment: not a problem, I wasn't the nicests. And also, sometimes language barriers intervene too (what is perfectly acceptable in other languages, sounds rude in english), as this is an international website.